# Preserve executable bit for script in google chrome extension

Tags: c++, python, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, posix

I am developing a chrome extension.  The extension contains an NPAPI plugin.  The plugin executes a python script that comes packaged in the extension using the popen C++ function.  During development all worked well.  Once I packaged the extension and installed the crx file, nothing worked correctly.  I found out its because the python script in the unpacked extension directory that was created by chrome during installation does not have the executable bit set.  Once I go ahead and set this (chmod a+x script.py) everything works as expected.

So, my question is.  How do I preserve the executable bit on a script file in a chrome extension package?

BTW, I am working on OSX and this python script only needs to run on the Mac/Linux version of the extension, not Windows.

Comment: why not do `python script.py`?

Comment: Ok wow, can't believe I didn't think of that.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> why not do python script.py?

Thanks to rsanchez: [Preserve executable bit for script in google chrome extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19052896/preserve-executable-bit-for-script-in-google-chrome-extension#comment28160153_19052896)